# Create 32-bit and 64-bit Static Library for Devices and Simulators - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit, static-libraries, 32-bit

I've got this SDK that supports 64-bit. For whatever reason, the library does not build on iOS simulators. To circumvent this I've created my own static library that instantiates the headers and implements everything. This method has always worked and allowed me to build and run the project on a simulator and devices (The standard library is used for devices and my static library is used for simulators).

Now that we have 64-bit and 32-bit devices and simulators, my static library does not build for 32-bit simulators. However, it does build for all devices (32-bit and 64-bit) and 64-bit simulators.

Does anyone know how to create a static library that works for both 32-bit and 64-bit devices and simulators?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to create fat library which is a combination of libraries for different architecture. have alook at this gist [Create fat library](https://gist.github.com/rehos/7856163)

Comment: Yes, I actually figured that out and forgot to post an answer. Thanks